# Rails mongoid find all users with X associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Sorry for this simple yet confusing (to me) question. 
I'm using Mongodb with rails.

```
class User
has_many :albums, dependent: :destroy
field    :role,   type: String,  default:  ''
```

I want to find all Users with a role of "accountant" and "manager" who have at least 3 albums.

I know it's supposed to be something like:

```
@selected = User.all.include(:albums).where(role: ['accountant', 'manager'].any, 'count(albums) > 3')
```

If you could let me know what the syntax is and maybe have a reference to a guide that helps explain how associations in mongodb with rails are accessed, I'd really appreciate it.